# CLR Strict Security on SQL Server 2017 - The assemblies are signed but suddenly 'clr strict security' exception appears again

Tags: c#, certificate, sql-server-2017, code-access-security

I created and installed certificate in my SQL Server 2017 (used `CREATE CERTIFICATE MyCertificate FROM BINARY`) and signed my assemblies, based on what described here: [Impact of CLR Strict Security configuration setting in SQL Server 2017](https://www.sqlshack.com/impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/).
Everything worked fine for about 2 years but suddenly I'm getting the 'clr strict security' exception  again -

> CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'MyAssembly' with
> the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict
> security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends
> that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that
> has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.
> Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using
> sp_add_trusted_assembly.

My certificates and assembly didn't change (the certificate expiration is set to - "2022-12-20 12:00:00.000"). What could be the cause?

Comment: Is there an expiry date associated with the certificate? Could it have elapsed?

Comment: @sTTu Sorry, forgot to mention it but no, the expiration is set to - "2022-12-20 12:00:00.000"